# Distinguish Activities WhatId, Whether it's Lead Id or Opportunity Id

Tags: integration, activities

I'm pulling the tasks table out of SFDC into another internal company system, where one fk column can only reference one foreign table. So I need to distinguish whether a task row's WhatId corresponds to a lead or an opportunity, and separate it into two fk columns.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by checking the first 3 characters of the ID. All the leads will have `00Q` and all opportunities will have `006` as the first 3 characters in the `WhatId` lookup value.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some further detail we use a formula like this (adding object support as necessary):

```
CASE(LEFT(WhatId,3), 
"001","Account", 
"701","Campaign", 
"500","Case", 
"a0B","Feedback", /*Custom object*/
"006","Opportunity", 
"-")
```

For reference these are the standard "decoded" 3 character Ids (taken from: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005995&language=en_US):

> Entity                                                        Prefix
>
> ```
> ACCOUNT                         '001'
> NOTE                            '002'
> CONTACT                         '003'
> USERS                           '005'
> OPPORTUNITY                     '006'
> ACTIVITY                        '007'
> OPPORTUNITY_HISTORY             '008'
> FORECAST_ITEM                   '00A'
> FILTER                          '00B'
> DELETE_EVENT                    '00C'
> ORGANIZATION                    '00D'
> USER_ROLE                       '00E'
> QUEUE                           '00G'
> GROUPS                          '00G'
> PARTNER                         '00I'
> OPPORTUNITY_COMPETITOR          '00J'
> OPPORTUNITY_CONTACT_ROLE        '00K'
> CUSTOM_FIELD_DEFINITION         '00N'
> REPORT                          '00O'
> ATTACHMENT                      '00P'
> LEAD                            '00Q'
> IMPORT_QUEUE                    '00S'
> TASK                            '00T'
> EVENT                           '00U'
> EMAIL_TEMPLATE                  '00X'
> EMAIL_TEMP                      '00Y'
> COMMENTS                        '00a'
> CUSTOM_RESOURCE_LINK            '00b'
> TRAINING                        '00c'
> PROFILE                         '00e'
> MH_BLUESHEET                    '00f'
> MH_GOLDSHEET                    '00g'
> LAYOUT                          '00h'
> PRICEBOOK_MAPPING               '00i'
> PRICEBOOK_ENTRY_MAPPING         '00j'
> OPPORTUNITY_LINEITEM            '00k'
> FOLDER                          '00l'
> EMAIL_ATTACHMENT_LOOKUP         '00m'
> EMAIL_ATTACHMENT_ARCHIVE        '00n'
> LINEITEM_SCHEDULE               '00o'
> USER_TEAM_MEMBER                '00p'
> OPP_TEAM_MEMBER                 '00q'
> ACC_SHARE                       '00r'
> ACC_SHARE_DEFAULT               '00s'
> OPP_SHARE                       '00t'
> OPP_SHARE_DEFAULT               '00u'
> CAMPAIGN_MEMBER                 '00v'
> PAYMENT_APPLICATION             '00w'
> BILLED_PRODUCT                  '00x'
> PURCHASE_RULE                   '00y'
> PURCHASE_RULE_ENTRY             '00z'
> CASE_SOLUTION                   '010'
> GROUP_MEMBER                    '011'
> RECORD_TYPE                     '012'
> RECORD_TYPE_PICKLIST            '013'
> PROFILE_RECORD_TYPE             '014'
> DOCUMENT                        '015'
> BRAND_TEMPLATE                  '016'
> ENTITY_HISTORY                  '017'
> EMAIL_STATUS                    '018'
> BUSINESS_PROCESS                '019'
> BUSINESS_PROCESS_PICKLIST       '01A'
> LAYOUT_SECTION                  '01B'
> LAYOUT_ITEM                     '01C'
> PROFILE_LAYOUT                  '01G'
> MAILMERGE_TEMPLATE              '01H'
> CUSTOM_ENTITY_DEFINITION        '01I'
> PICKLIST_MASTER                 '01J'
> CURRENCY_TYPE                   '01L'
> ACC_TEAM_MEMBER                 '01M'
> ACTIVE_CONTENT                  '01N'
> USER_UI_CONFIGURATION           '01O'
> PROFILE_TAB_CONFIGURATION       '01P'
> WORKFLOW_RULE                   '01Q'
> RULE_FILTER                     '01R'
> RULE_FILTER_ITEM                '01S'
> RULE_FILTER_ACTION              '01T'
> ACTION_ASSIGN_ESCALATE          '01U'
> ACTION_TASK                     '01V'
> ACTION_EMAIL                    '01W'
> ACTION_EMAIL_RECIPIENT          '01X'
> CAMPAIGN_MEMBER_STATUS          '01Y'
> DASHBOARD                       '01Z'
> DASHBOARD_COMPONENT             '01a'
> FILTER_ITEM                     '01b'
> FILTER_COLUMN                   '01c'
> FOLDER_GROUPS                   '01d'
> PICKLIST_SET                    '01e'
> WEBEX_MEETING                   '01f'
> API_QUERY                       '01g'
> TRANSLATION                     '01h'
> TRANSLATION_USER                '01i'
> TRANSLATION_VALUE               '01j'
> PROFILE_FLS_ITEM                '01k'
> ACTION_RESPONSE                 '01l'
> BUSINESS_HOURS                  '01m'
> CASE_SHARE                      '01n'
> LEAD_SHARE                      '01o'
> CUSTOM_TAB_DEFINITION           '01r'
> PRICEBOOK2                      '01s'
> PRODUCT2                        '01t'
> PRICEBOOK_ENTRY                 '01u'
> PRICEBOOK_SHARE                 '01v'
> OPP_UPDATE_REMINDER             '01w'
> OPP_UPDATE_REMINDER_STATS       '01x'
> CASE_SHARE_DEFAULT              '01y'
> CASE_ESCALATION                 '01z'
> EVENT_ATTENDEE                  '020'
> QUANTITY_FORECAST               '021'
> FISCAL_YEAR_SETTINGS            '022'
> APP_CALENDAR                    '023'
> APP_CALENDAR_SHARING            '024'
> LIST_LAYOUT_ITEM                '025'
> PERIOD                          '026'
> REVENUE_FORECAST                '027'
> OPPORTUNITY_OVERRIDE            '028'
> LINEITEM_OVERRIDE               '029'
> LEAD_SHARE_DEFAULT              '02A'
> LABEL_DEFINITION                '02B'
> LABEL_DATA                      '02C'
> CASES_HISTORY2                  '02D'
> HELP_SETTING                    '02E'
> CUSTOM_FIELD_MAP                '02F'
> MH_GOLD_PROGRAM                 '02H'
> MH_GOLD_INFORMATION             '02I'
> MH_GOLD_CONTACT                 '02J'
> MH_GOLD_ACTION                  '02K'
> MH_CUSTOMER_CRITERION           '02L'
> MH_GREENSHEET                   '02M'
> MH_GREEN_GIVE_INFO              '02N'
> MH_GREEN_GET_INFO               '02O'
> MH_CONTACT_ROLE                 '02P'
> MH_INFORMATION                  '02Q'
> USER_PREFERENCE2                '02R'
> HTML_COMPONENT                  '02S'
> CUSTOM_PAGE                     '02T'
> CUSTOM_PAGE_ITEM                '02U'
> PAGE_COMPONENT                  '02V'
> CUSTOM_PAGE_PROFILE             '02X'
> USER_COMPONENT_DATA             '02Y'
> ACCOUNT_CONTACT_ROLE            '02Z'
> CONTRACT_CONTACT_ROLE           '02a'
> COMPONENT_RESOURCE_LINK         '02b'
> DIVISION                        '02d'
> DIVISION_WORKFLOW_RULE          '02e'
> DELEGATE_GROUP                  '02f'
> DELEGATE_GROUP_MEMBER           '02g'
> DELEGATE_GROUP_GRANT            '02h'
> ASSET                           '02i'
> PROFILE_ENTITY_PERMISSIONS      '02j'
> LIST_LAYOUT                     '02k'
> OUTBOUND_QUEUE                  '02l'
> CUSTOM_INDEX                    '02m'
> CATEGORY_NODE                   '02n'
> CATEGORY_DATA                   '02o'
> DIV_TRANSFER_EVENT              '02p'
> LAYOUT_ITEM_COLUMN              '02q'
> OPPORTUNITY_ALERT               '02r'
> EMAIL_MESSAGE                   '02s'
> EMAIL_ROUTING_ADDRESS           '02t'
> TAB_SET                         '02u'
> TAB_SET_MEMBER                  '02v'
> LOGIN_IP_RANGE                  '02w'
> LOGIN_HOURS                     '02x'
> REPORT_AGGREGATE                '02y'
> REPORT_COLOR_RANGE              '02z'
> PROFILE_TAB_SET                 '030'
> USER_TAB_SET_MEMBER             '031'
> ACC_TERRITORY_RULE              '032'
> PROJECT                         '033'
> PROJECT_MEMBER                  '034'
> SELF_SERVICE_USER               '035'
> JOB_QUEUE                       '036'
> REPORT_COLUMN                   '037'
> REPORT_FILTER_ITEM              '038'
> REPORT_BREAK                    '039'
> DEPENDENT_PICKLIST              '03a'
> PACKAGE_EXPORT                  '03b'
> LAYOUT_RIGHT_PANEL              '03c'
> CUSTOM_SETUP_DEFINITION         '03e'
> CUSTOM_SETUP                    '03f'
> REPORT_PARAM                    '040'
> ACC_TERRITORY_ASSIGN            '041'
> ACC_TERR_ASSIGN_RULE_ITEM       '042'
> OUTBOUND_FIELD                  '043'
> USER_TERRITORY                  '04S'
> TERRITORY                       '04T'
> DNB_ACCOUNT_MAPPING             '04U'
> DNB_FIELD                       '04V'
> REVENUE_FORECAST_HISTORY        '04W'
> QUANTITY_FORECAST_HISTORY       '04X'
> CONTENTVERSION                  '068'
> CONTENTDOCUMENT                 '069'
> ENTITY_PERMISSION               '110'
> SFDC_PARTNER                    '204'
> SFDC_DIVISION                   '208'
> CASES                           '500'
> SOLUTION                        '501'
> BILLING_DIVISION                '600'
> BILLING_ORDER                   '601'
> CURRENCY                        '602'
> PLAN                            '604'
> PRODUCT                         '605'
> BILLING_ORDER_ITEM              '606'
> PLAN_PRODUCT                    '607'
> CAMPAIGN                        '701'
> FIELD_HISTORY                   '737'
> UI_STYLE_DEFINITION             '766'
> UI_STYLE                        '777'
> CONTRACT                        '800'
> ORDERS                          '801'
> ORDER_ITEM                      '802'
> INVOICE                         '803'
> INVOICE_ITEM                    '804'
> PAYMENT                         '805'
> APPROVAL                        '806'
> URI_BLOCK_RULE                  '807'
> CUSTOM_ENTITY_DATA              'a00'
> ACCOUNT                         '001'
> NOTE                            '002'
> CONTACT                         '003'
> USERS                           '005'
> OPPORTUNITY                     '006'
> ACTIVITY                        '007'
> OPPORTUNITY_HISTORY             '008'
> FORECAST_ITEM                   '00A'
> FILTER                          '00B'
> DELETE_EVENT                    '00C'
> ORGANIZATION                    '00D'
> USER_ROLE                       '00E'
> QUEUE                           '00G'
> GROUPS                          '00G'
> PARTNER                         '00I'
> OPPORTUNITY_COMPETITOR          '00J'
> OPPORTUNITY_CONTACT_ROLE        '00K'
> CUSTOM_FIELD_DEFINITION         '00N'
> REPORT                          '00O'
> ATTACHMENT                      '00P'
> LEAD                            '00Q'
> IMPORT_QUEUE                    '00S'
> TASK                            '00T'
> EVENT                           '00U'
> EMAIL_TEMPLATE                  '00X'
> EMAIL_TEMP                      '00Y'
> COMMENTS                        '00a'
> CUSTOM_RESOURCE_LINK            '00b'
> TRAINING                        '00c'
> PROFILE                         '00e'
> MH_BLUESHEET                    '00f'
> MH_GOLDSHEET                    '00g'
> LAYOUT                          '00h'
> PRICEBOOK_MAPPING               '00i'
> PRICEBOOK_ENTRY_MAPPING         '00j'
> OPPORTUNITY_LINEITEM            '00k'
> FOLDER                          '00l'
> EMAIL_ATTACHMENT_LOOKUP         '00m'
> EMAIL_ATTACHMENT_ARCHIVE        '00n'
> LINEITEM_SCHEDULE               '00o'
> USER_TEAM_MEMBER                '00p'
> OPP_TEAM_MEMBER                 '00q'
> ACC_SHARE                       '00r'
> ACC_SHARE_DEFAULT               '00s'
> OPP_SHARE                       '00t'
> OPP_SHARE_DEFAULT               '00u'
> CAMPAIGN_MEMBER                 '00v'
> PAYMENT_APPLICATION             '00w'
> BILLED_PRODUCT                  '00x'
> PURCHASE_RULE                   '00y'
> PURCHASE_RULE_ENTRY             '00z'
> CASE_SOLUTION                   '010'
> GROUP_MEMBER                    '011'
> RECORD_TYPE                     '012'
> RECORD_TYPE_PICKLIST            '013'
> PROFILE_RECORD_TYPE             '014'
> DOCUMENT                        '015'
> BRAND_TEMPLATE                  '016'
> ENTITY_HISTORY                  '017'
> EMAIL_STATUS                    '018'
> BUSINESS_PROCESS                '019'
> BUSINESS_PROCESS_PICKLIST       '01A'
> LAYOUT_SECTION                  '01B'
> LAYOUT_ITEM                     '01C'
> PROFILE_LAYOUT                  '01G'
> MAILMERGE_TEMPLATE              '01H'
> CUSTOM_ENTITY_DEFINITION        '01I'
> PICKLIST_MASTER                 '01J'
> CURRENCY_TYPE                   '01L'
> ACC_TEAM_MEMBER                 '01M'
> ACTIVE_CONTENT                  '01N'
> USER_UI_CONFIGURATION           '01O'
> PROFILE_TAB_CONFIGURATION       '01P'
> WORKFLOW_RULE                   '01Q'
> RULE_FILTER                     '01R'
> RULE_FILTER_ITEM                '01S'
> RULE_FILTER_ACTION              '01T'
> ACTION_ASSIGN_ESCALATE          '01U'
> ACTION_TASK                     '01V'
> ACTION_EMAIL                    '01W'
> ACTION_EMAIL_RECIPIENT          '01X'
> CAMPAIGN_MEMBER_STATUS          '01Y'
> DASHBOARD                       '01Z'
> DASHBOARD_COMPONENT             '01a'
> FILTER_ITEM                     '01b'
> FILTER_COLUMN                   '01c'
> FOLDER_GROUPS                   '01d'
> PICKLIST_SET                    '01e'
> WEBEX_MEETING                   '01f'
> API_QUERY                       '01g'
> TRANSLATION                     '01h'
> TRANSLATION_USER                '01i'
> TRANSLATION_VALUE               '01j'
> PROFILE_FLS_ITEM                '01k'
> ACTION_RESPONSE                 '01l'
> BUSINESS_HOURS                  '01m'
> CASE_SHARE                      '01n'
> LEAD_SHARE                      '01o'
> CUSTOM_TAB_DEFINITION           '01r'
> PRICEBOOK2                      '01s'
> PRODUCT2                        '01t'
> PRICEBOOK_ENTRY                 '01u'
> PRICEBOOK_SHARE                 '01v'
> OPP_UPDATE_REMINDER             '01w'
> OPP_UPDATE_REMINDER_STATS       '01x'
> CASE_SHARE_DEFAULT              '01y'
> CASE_ESCALATION                 '01z'
> EVENT_ATTENDEE                  '020'
> QUANTITY_FORECAST               '021'
> FISCAL_YEAR_SETTINGS            '022'
> APP_CALENDAR                    '023'
> APP_CALENDAR_SHARING            '024'
> LIST_LAYOUT_ITEM                '025'
> PERIOD                          '026'
> REVENUE_FORECAST                '027'
> OPPORTUNITY_OVERRIDE            '028'
> LINEITEM_OVERRIDE               '029'
> LEAD_SHARE_DEFAULT              '02A'
> LABEL_DEFINITION                '02B'
> LABEL_DATA                      '02C'
> CASES_HISTORY2                  '02D'
> HELP_SETTING                    '02E'
> CUSTOM_FIELD_MAP                '02F'
> MH_GOLD_PROGRAM                 '02H'
> MH_GOLD_INFORMATION             '02I'
> MH_GOLD_CONTACT                 '02J'
> MH_GOLD_ACTION                  '02K'
> MH_CUSTOMER_CRITERION           '02L'
> MH_GREENSHEET                   '02M'
> MH_GREEN_GIVE_INFO              '02N'
> MH_GREEN_GET_INFO               '02O'
> MH_CONTACT_ROLE                 '02P'
> MH_INFORMATION                  '02Q'
> USER_PREFERENCE2                '02R'
> HTML_COMPONENT                  '02S'
> CUSTOM_PAGE                     '02T'
> CUSTOM_PAGE_ITEM                '02U'
> PAGE_COMPONENT                  '02V'
> CUSTOM_PAGE_PROFILE             '02X'
> USER_COMPONENT_DATA             '02Y'
> ACCOUNT_CONTACT_ROLE            '02Z'
> CONTRACT_CONTACT_ROLE           '02a'
> COMPONENT_RESOURCE_LINK         '02b'
> DIVISION                        '02d'
> DIVISION_WORKFLOW_RULE          '02e'
> DELEGATE_GROUP                  '02f'
> DELEGATE_GROUP_MEMBER           '02g'
> DELEGATE_GROUP_GRANT            '02h'
> ASSET                           '02i'
> PROFILE_ENTITY_PERMISSIONS      '02j'
> LIST_LAYOUT                     '02k'
> OUTBOUND_QUEUE                  '02l'
> CUSTOM_INDEX                    '02m'
> CATEGORY_NODE                   '02n'
> CATEGORY_DATA                   '02o'
> DIV_TRANSFER_EVENT              '02p'
> LAYOUT_ITEM_COLUMN              '02q'
> OPPORTUNITY_ALERT               '02r'
> EMAIL_MESSAGE                   '02s'
> EMAIL_ROUTING_ADDRESS           '02t'
> TAB_SET                         '02u'
> TAB_SET_MEMBER                  '02v'
> LOGIN_IP_RANGE                  '02w'
> LOGIN_HOURS                     '02x'
> REPORT_AGGREGATE                '02y'
> REPORT_COLOR_RANGE              '02z'
> PROFILE_TAB_SET                 '030'
> USER_TAB_SET_MEMBER             '031'
> ACC_TERRITORY_RULE              '032'
> PROJECT                         '033'
> PROJECT_MEMBER                  '034'
> SELF_SERVICE_USER               '035'
> JOB_QUEUE                       '036'
> REPORT_COLUMN                   '037'
> REPORT_FILTER_ITEM              '038'
> REPORT_BREAK                    '039'
> DEPENDENT_PICKLIST              '03a'
> PACKAGE_EXPORT                  '03b'
> LAYOUT_RIGHT_PANEL              '03c'
> CUSTOM_SETUP_DEFINITION         '03e'
> CUSTOM_SETUP                    '03f'
> REPORT_PARAM                    '040'
> ACC_TERRITORY_ASSIGN            '041'
> ACC_TERR_ASSIGN_RULE_ITEM       '042'
> OUTBOUND_FIELD                  '043'
> USER_TERRITORY                  '04S'
> TERRITORY                       '04T'
> DNB_ACCOUNT_MAPPING             '04U'
> DNB_FIELD                       '04V'
> REVENUE_FORECAST_HISTORY        '04W'
> QUANTITY_FORECAST_HISTORY       '04X'
> CONTENTVERSION                  '068'
> CONTENTDOCUMENT                 '069'
> ENTITY_PERMISSION               '110'
> SFDC_PARTNER                    '204'
> SFDC_DIVISION                   '208'
> CASES                           '500'
> SOLUTION                        '501'
> BILLING_DIVISION                '600'
> BILLING_ORDER                   '601'
> CURRENCY                        '602'
> PLAN                            '604'
> PRODUCT                         '605'
> BILLING_ORDER_ITEM              '606'
> PLAN_PRODUCT                    '607'
> CAMPAIGN                        '701'
> FIELD_HISTORY                   '737'
> UI_STYLE_DEFINITION             '766'
> UI_STYLE                        '777'
> CONTRACT                        '800'
> ORDERS                          '801'
> ORDER_ITEM                      '802'
> INVOICE                         '803'
> INVOICE_ITEM                    '804'
> PAYMENT                         '805'
> APPROVAL                        '806'
> URI_BLOCK_RULE                  '807'
> PERMISSION SET                  '0PS'
> CUSTOM_ENTITY_DATA              'a00'
> ```