# Unable to Report Events(Activities) with Direct Relation to Account via WhatId

Tags: reporting, activities, custom-reports

Is there any way we can use standard reporting capability to fetch Events where WhatId is associated with an Account record ?

I am able to fetch Events which are linked (in-directly) with Account via their Associated Contact (WhoId), but unable to get only results where report can show Events only associated with Accounts(WhatId).

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distinguish Activities WhatId, Whether it's Lead Id or Opportunity Id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48263/distinguish-activities-whatid-whether-its-lead-id-or-opportunity-id)

Comment: Use a [row-level formula](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/rd-summary-formulas/rd-row-level-formulas) based on the answer above.

Comment: @identigral The above approach will only work when you are handling Activities via API but via standard reporting we cannot access Id of 'WhatId' field and hence I cannot find above solution useful !

Comment: Standard reporting does allow this and then some. In fact, our comment above regarding using a row-level formula via a prefix is an unnecessarily complicated approach. A simple, out of the box solution is a report on Activities that has _Account Name is/is not blank_ filter. The report automatically pulls a related Account. Just tried this in a dev org, can confirm that this works.